# viewChild inside *ngIf resulting undefined reference

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I would like to make a loading When requesting data from ngrx+ api http request

I have a state that contain loading boolean, and another with raw data.

I set loading to false when data arrive.

the problem `viewChild` don't find reference because data arrive before loading set to false.

I get error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Here's the template

```
<div *ngIf="isLoading; else kpi"><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></div>
<ng-template #kpi>
  <div class="chartWrapper">
    <div class="scrollArea">
      <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
        <canvas #lineChart id="lineChart" width="1200" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <canvas #stickyAxis id="chartAxis" height="400" width="0"></canvas>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

in component

```
export class BranchKpisComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('lineChart', { static: true }) private chartRef;
```

I'm using ngrx store

I have the selectors

```
selectLoadings$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectLoadings));
selectedDataByBranch$ = this.store.pipe(
 select(selectBranchDirections, {
   branchId: this.branchId,
   location: 'directionsByBranch',
   dir: 0
 })
```

inside `ngOnchange()` I subscribe to loading and data observable ( separately )

```
this.selectLoadings$.subscribe(
  loading => (this.isLoading = loading.directionsByBranch[this.branchId])
);

this.selectedDataByBranch$
      .pipe(filter(data => Object.keys(data).length > 0))
      .subscribe(selectedDataByBranch => {
        this.trainsDatasets = this.getDatasets(selectedDataByBranch);
        this.context = this.chartRef.nativeElement; ### Error undefined chartRef
```

Inside reducer when I get data I set loading to false

```
case ESchedulesActions.GetAllSchedulesByDirectionSuccess: {
  return {
    ...state,
    directionsByBranch: {
      ...state.directionsByBranch,
      [action.payload[1]]: action.payload[0]
    },
    loadings: {
      ...state.loadings,
      directionsByBranch: {
        ...state.loadings.directionsByBranch,
        [action.payload[1]]: false
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: it itself says chartRef is undefined. Did you add any reference ??

Comment: yes I have Updated my answer

Comment: The problem is that changing loading to false only updates the view child after the current event handling phase finishes. The simplest hack is to add a setTimeout before the code that is using the reference. The better solution is not to have a view child component and communicate thorough the HTML instead so that angular will set your inputs when rendering it, instead of doing it from the controller/component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [hidden] instead of *ngIf. It will still have the element you want to view in the DOM. Would need another one instead of the else which is the opposite.

```
<div [hidden]="!isLoading"><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></div>
<ng-template [hidden]="isLoading">
  <div class="chartWrapper">
    <div class="scrollArea">
      <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
        <canvas #lineChart id="lineChart" width="1200" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <canvas #stickyAxis id="chartAxis" height="400" width="0"></canvas>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

In terms of performance there won't be much difference if at all due to the size of the code.

Comment: This is one way to do it, but it does have the drawback of instantiating part of the DOM when you don't need it. This can be problematic when you're rendering a lot of components that get initialized and are part of change detection.

Comment: See the answer marked as accepted for a better option

Answer (score 0):

`viewChild` should be implemented in this way. From the above, I think you implemented viewChild in wrong way.

```
import { Component,
         ViewChild,
         AfterViewInit,
         ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('someInput') someInput: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someInput.nativeElement.value = "Anchovies! ";
  }
}
```

so your updated code block will be

```
export class BranchKpisComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('lineChart', { static: true }) chartRef:ElementRef;
```

Dont forget to import `ElementRef`

Comment: You are not explaining what the problem was, and I dunt think this will solve the problem

Comment: @JuanMendes i think it seems like viewChild is implemented is wrong, so the chartRef here is undefined. thats what i got from the block he posted.

Comment: I think it's because of the `ngIf` condition ,even I use `ngafterInitView` the reference does not exist yet because the condition is false so the  ref `div` is not yet on DOM, 

I would be able to get the reference when data came from API,  then update the dom and at this time I could get the reference, But I don't know how

Comment: @infodev As I explained in my comment.

Comment: @AkhilAravind It's only undefined because he's checking for it while changing the flag that re-renders the template. You have to wait until the template renders again.

Comment: Hey to fix this problem use 
    @ViewChild('lineChart', { static: false }) chartRef:ElementRef;
An explanation of why is here, https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration, but basically when static it true means the child component is not inside any structural directive like ngIf or ngFor, so it can be found faster and is available on ngInit, when static is false is the opposite is inside a directive like ngIf or similar structural directive so angular can only find it after a ngAfterViewInit when the conditions of ngIf etc have been evaluated